# Grouping array by string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Need a hand tidying this up a little.
I have a script (see below) that trawls through a Google sheet and checks if a project is approaching its due date or if it has breached its due date. That part is working. What I need it to do is to send an email to the Resource assigned when its approaching or has breached. That's simple enough, mailApp works fine. But what I want to do is to group the information as to not spam people's mailboxes.

**Code:**

```
function mailBot() {
  var warningDays = 14;
  var data = cwSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.slice(1).forEach(function(row) {
    var user = row[0];
    var userEmail = buildMailAddress(user);
    var projectName = row[3];
    var date = row[8];
    var today = new Date();
    if (
      row[0] !== "" &&
      row[0] !== "Unassigned" &&
      row[0] !== "Proof of Concept"
    ) {
      var dueDate = new Date(date);
      if (dateDiff(dueDate, today) >= 1) {
//        Logger.log("**BREACHED** | %s", row);
//       TODO: Group results to send a single mail rather than multiple mails.
      } else if (dateDiff(today, dueDate) <= warningDays) {
//        Logger.log("**DUE** | %s", row);
//       TODO: Group results to send a single mail rather than multiple mails.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Output of log:**

```
[19-01-22 02:24:40:852 PST] **BREACHED** | [Darth Vader, Link, , Some project, , Project, Group, Shaping, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019, Green, , , ]
[19-01-22 02:24:40:853 PST] **BREACHED** | [Darth Vader, Link, www.google.com, Some project, , Project, Department, Shaping, Fri Oct 26 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, Green, , , ]
[19-01-22 02:24:40:855 PST] **BREACHED** | [Frodo Baggins, , , Test Due Date 1, , Project, JL, Development, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019, , , , ]
[19-01-22 02:24:40:856 PST] **BREACHED** | [Frodo Baggins, , , Test Due Date 2, , Small Dev, Waitrose, Development, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019, , , , ]
[19-01-22 02:24:40:857 PST] **BREACHED** | [Frodo Baggins, , , Test Due Date 3, , Project, Group, Development, Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019, , , , ]
[19-01-22 02:24:40:857 PST] **BREACHED** | [Frodo Baggins, , , Test Due Date 3, , Small Dev, I&S, Development, Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019, , , , ]
```

Using the above log as an example, Darth Vader would get 1 email with the contents of 2 alerts in it. Frodo would get 1 email with the contents of 4 alerts in it. Is anyone able to give me a steer on how to best achieve this?

**UPDATE 1**

Given the code from cen0r below that I adjusted to work with GAS

```
function mailBot() {
  var warningDays = 14;
  var data = cwSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();

  // Parse the data using custom function
  var parsed = parseData(data);

  // Filter entries that are breached
  var breached = parsed.filter(function(entry) {
    return dateDiff(entry.date, today) >= 1;
  });

  // Group breached entries by user and do something with them
  groupBy(breached, "user").map(function(group) {
    // Here group is an array of entries for one user
    // You can send one email for all breached entries here
  });

  // Filter entries that are due
  var due = parsed.filter(
    function(entry) {
      return (
        dateDiff(today, entry.date) <= warningDays &&
        dateDiff(entry.date, today) < 1
      );
    } // This is so there won't be 2 emails sent for breached & due
  );

  // Group due entries by user and do something with them
  groupBy(breached, "user").map(function(group) {
  Logger.log(group)
    // Here group is an array of entries for one user
    // You can send one email for all due entries here
  });
}

// Parses the data from your input
function parseData(data) {
  // Parse the data
  var parsed = data.slice(1).map(function(row) {
    var user = row[0];
    var userEmail = buildMailAddress(user);
    var today = new Date();
    var projectName = row[3];
    var date = new Date(row[8]);

    return {
      user: user,
      userEmail: userEmail,
      projectName: projectName,
      date: date,
      today: today
    };
  });

  // Filter entries that you want to do something with
  return parsed.filter(function(entry) {
    return (
      entry.user !== "" &&
      entry.user !== "Unassigned" &&
      entry.user !== "Proof of Concept"
    );
  });
}

// Groups array entries according to a property of the entry (the key)
function groupBy(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
}
```

This now produces the error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function map in object [object Object]. (line
>   25, file "0 - Main")

Which is refrencing this line of code:

```
groupBy(breached, "user").map(function(group) {
});
```

Comment: The simple object `{}` is not an `Array`. Thus, the error. If you have a second question you should not hijack your first question. You should do the necessary research and experimentation first, and only ask a new question if necessary. If you have an Issue with an answer given, you should be commenting on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first returning an array of parsed data, then gouping them and finally sending emails. Note that I used some ES6 syntax, if this doesn't work for you I can adjust it. Like so:

```
// Parses the data from your input
function parseData(data) {

    // Parse the data
    var parsed = data.slice(1).map(function(row) {
        var user = row[0];
        var userEmail = buildMailAddress(user);
        var projectName = row[3];
        var date = new Date(row[8]);

        return {
            "user": user, 
            "userEmail": userEmail, 
            "projectName": projectName,
            "date": date,
            "today": today
        };
    )};

    // Filter entries that you want to do something with
    return parsed.filter(entry =>
        entry.user !== "" &&
        entry.user !== "Unassigned" &&
        entry.user !== "Proof of Concept"
    );
};

// Groups array entries according to a property of the entry (the key)
function groupBy(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
    }, {});
};

function mailBot() {
    var warningDays = 14;
    var data = cwSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var today = new Date();

    // Parse the data using custom function
    var parsed = parseData(data);

    // Filter entries that are breached
    var breached = parsed.filter(funciton(entry) {
        return dateDiff(entry.date, today) >= 1;
    });

    // Group breached entries by user and do something with them
    var breachedGroup = groupBy(breached,"user");
    Object.keys(breachedGroup).forEach(function (key) {
        var group = breachedGroup[key];
        // Here group is an array of entries for one user
        // You can send one email for all breached entries here
        console.log(g[key]);
    })

    // Filter entries that are due
    var due = parsed.filter(function(entry) { 
        return dateDiff(today, entry.date) <= warningDays &&
        dateDiff(entry.date, today) < 1 // This is so there won't be 2 emails sent for breached & due
    });

    // Group due entries by user and do something with them
    var dueGroup = groupBy(due,"user");
    Object.keys(dueGroup).forEach(function (key) {
        var group = dueGroup[key];
        // Here group is an array of entries for one user
        // You can send one email for all breached entries here
    });
};
```

Comment: Arrow syntax is not available. But the rest are available.

Comment: Unfortunately, GAS doesn't support ES6 (yet). Could you adjust, please?

Comment: This I have it, used Babel to decompile the ES6.

Comment: Aha, getting a similar response to some of the testing I did - 
'TypeError: Cannot find function map in object [object Object]'


Updating my original question with the code in use.

Comment: Whoop, sorry about that. I forgot how groupBy works here. I fixed it in the code. I also removed the Arrow syntax. This should work

Answer (score 0):

Basically this log is available when the foreach loop is complete so you need to create an object (with  two properties name and array of messages) outside the loop and fill this log information into that. While filling you can check whether user exists in that or not and then after this loop you can easily send mail to the users.

Else you need to use jquery libraries, I am not sure you are willing to use them or not.